# Get the value of a variable stocked in a js code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I am trying to get the dates when available on this [datepicker](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Sans-titre_7.jpg)

When availables , the dates are saved in the variable available_dates inside a js script which fills the html input.

HTML of the input :

```
<input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control-input app_date validate" style="width: 260px;" id="app_date" name="app_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" onchange="this.form.submit();showLoader();" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

How can i retrieve the values from available_dates when the dates are availables, get them to my python script to select one of them.

The following python script didn't work :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='app_date']").click()
time.sleep(3)

try:
  print([date.get_attribute("innerHTML") for date in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']//tr//td[@class='day activeClass' and @title='Book']")))])
except TimeoutException:
  print("No booking dates available for the current month")
driver.refresh()
```

JS script :

```js
<script type="text/javascript" xpath="1">

    var today = new Date();

    var dd = today.getDate()+1;

    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10){

        dd='0'+dd

    } 

    if(mm<10){

        mm='0'+mm

    } 



    var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;



    function formatDate(rawDate) {

      var day = ("0" + rawDate.getDate()).slice(-2);

      var month = ("0" + (rawDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

      return (day)+ "-" + (month)+ "-" +rawDate.getFullYear() ;

    }       



    $(document).ready(function() {



        var dt1  = '2023-02-14';

        var checkService  = 'Normal';

             $('.date_of_birth').datepicker({

                    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",

                    endDate: new Date(dt1),

                    startDate: '-100y',

                    autoclose: true,

                    startView: 2

              });



              $('.pptIssueDate').datepicker({

                    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",

                    endDate: new Date(dt1),

                    startDate: '-100y',

                    autoclose: true,

                    startView: 2

                });



              $('.passport_validate_till').datepicker({

                    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",

                    startDate: new Date(dt1),

                    autoclose: true,

                    startView: 2

              });



        var dt4  = '2023-02-15';

        var blocked_dates = ["01-01-2023","02-01-2023","06-01-2023","13-01-2023","20-01-2023","27-01-2023","03-02-2023","10-02-2023","17-02-2023","24-02-2023","01-01-2023","02-01-2023","06-01-2023","13-01-2023","20-01-2023","27-01-2023","03-02-2023","10-02-2023","17-02-2023","24-02-2023"];

        var available_dates = [];

        var fullCapicity_dates = ["15-02-2023","16-02-2023","20-02-2023","21-02-2023","22-02-2023","23-02-2023","27-02-2023","28-02-2023"];

        var offDates_dates = ["17-02-2023","18-02-2023","19-02-2023","24-02-2023","25-02-2023","26-02-2023"];

        var allowArray = [1,2];

        if(checkService == 'Normal')

        {

            /*if((jQuery.inArray(2, allowArray)!='-1') || (jQuery.inArray(3, allowArray)!='-1') || (jQuery.inArray(4, allowArray)!='-1')) 

            {

                var classFull = 'fullcapspecial';

                var tooltipTitle = '&nbsp;';

                var backDatetitle = 'Not Allowed';

            }else{

                var classFull = 'fullcap';

                var tooltipTitle = 'Slots Full';

                var backDatetitle = 'Not Allowed';

            }*/



            var classFull = 'fullcap';

            var tooltipTitle = 'Slots Full';

            var backDatetitle = 'Not Allowed';



        }else{



            var classFull = 'fullcap';

            var tooltipTitle = 'Slots Full';

            var backDatetitle = 'Not Allowed';



        }



        $('.app_date').datepicker({



            language: "en",

            Default: true,

            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",

            startDate: new Date(dt4),

            endDate: '2023-02-28', 

            autoclose: true,

            forceParse:true,

            startView: 0,



            beforeShowDay: function(date){



                   var formattedDate = formatDate(date);



                   if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), blocked_dates) != -1){



                       return {



                          enabled : false,



                          classes: 'inactiveClass',



                          tooltip: 'Holiday'



                       };



                   }



                   if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), available_dates) != -1){



                       return {



                          enabled : true,



                          classes: 'activeClass',



                          tooltip: 'Book'



                       };



                   }



                   if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), fullCapicity_dates) != -1){



                       return {



                          enabled : false,



                          classes: classFull,



                          tooltip: tooltipTitle



                       };



                   }



                   if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), offDates_dates) != -1){



                       return {



                          enabled : false,



                          classes: 'offday',



                          tooltip: 'Off Day'



                       };



                   }



                   



                    return {



                      enabled : false,



                      tooltip: backDatetitle



                   };



                  return;



              }



        });



        /*====== CALL POP FOR PL/PT IN NORMAL CASE=======*/



        if(checkService == 'Normal')



        {



            if((jQuery.inArray(2, allowArray)!='-1') || (jQuery.inArray(3, allowArray)!='-1') || (jQuery.inArray(4, allowArray)!='-1')) 



            {



                /*$(document).on('click', '.fullcap,.fullcapspecial', function () {



                $(".datepicker").hide();



                $('.popupBG').show();



                $('#IDBodyPanel').show();



                });



                $(".popupCloseIcon").click(function() {



                $(".popupBG").hide();



                $("#IDBodyPanel").hide(); 



                });*/



            



                /*$('input[type=radio][name=serviceChange]').change(function() {



                if (this.value == 'Premium') {



                    $("#premiumService").prop('value', 'GO FOR PREMIUM');



                }



                else if (this.value == 'Prime') {



                    $("#premiumService").prop('value', 'GO FOR PRIME TIME');



                }



                



                });*/



            }



        }



        /*====== CALL POP FOR PL/PT IN NORMAL CASE=======*/



        var eventhandler = function(e) {



           e.preventDefault();      



        }



        if (checkService == 'Premium' || checkService == 'Prime' || checkService == 'Premium-Saturday') {



            $('input[name="vasId[]"]:checked').each(function() {



               $("#vasId"+this.value).bind('click', eventhandler);



            });



        }



        



        if (checkService != 'Premium')



        {



            $(document).on('click', '.chkbox', function () {



                if($(this).val() == 1)



                {



                    if($(this).is(":checked")){



                      //$("#vasId6").prop('checked', true);



                      //$("#vasId6").bind('click', eventhandler);



                    }else{



                      //$("#vasId6").prop('checked', false);    



                      //$("#vasId6").unbind('click', eventhandler);



                    }



                }



            });



        }



        



    });



    



    



    



</script>
```

Solved

Comment: @undetectedselenium Sir Debanjan could you please help?

Comment: Anybody who cares to help?

Comment: can any body help please?